# Selecting MySQL datetime in a range

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have seen at least 2 dozen questions just like this on StackOverflow but not a single one of the approved answers worked for me.

I am trying to run this MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM requests WHERE date_created between "2012-10-01 00:00:00" AND "2012-11-01 00:00:00"­
```

And the error that I'm getting is this:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '­ LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

I do not understand this error! I am not even using "limit" in my query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How you are trying to run that query? MySQL Workbench? PHP? Console?

Comment: I am running it through phpMyAdmin, Kamil

Comment: @nathanhayfield I'm not sure what you mean by that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
 SELECT * FROM requests 
 WHERE date_created between DATE('2012-10-01 00:00:00') 
                            AND DATE('2012-11-01 00:00:00'­)
```

Comment: This didn't work either, unfortunately... Thank you for trying

Comment: Yes, same error. I am entering these queries through phpMyAdmin. Perhaps that has something to do with the error?

Comment: If you have access of your mySQL, would you mind verifying it there? Because your query and this one, both look good to me. Also I would try stripping the time part from the query once.

Comment: Huh, it works. I thought I could reliably use phpMyAdmin to test MySQL queries but it seems as though I might be better off insally MySQL query browser. Thanks for the help, Yogendra.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, I would say the error is probably referring to another query in your code which actually has a "LIMIT 0, 30" in it.

Comment: If it helps, I am making these queries through phpMyAdmin. Could it be trying to add something for me somewhere and that's what's causing it? None of my queries contain a 'LIMIT'